# Component ref type in React Native with Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm just starting to use Typescript in React Native and need help with refs and their types.

Please, see my code below:

```
type MyComponentProps = {
  ref?: React.RefObject<typeof MyComponentViewNative>;
  style?: ViewStyle;
};

type MyComponentState = {
  permissionsGranted?: Boolean;
};

const ComponentName = 'MyComponentView';

const MyComponentViewNative =
  UIManager.getViewManagerConfig(ComponentName) != null
    ? requireNativeComponent<MyComponentProps>(ComponentName)
    : () => {
        throw new Error(LINKING_ERROR);
      };

export class MyComponentView extends React.PureComponent<{}, {}> {
  private viewRef: React.RefObject<typeof MyComponentViewNative> =
    React.createRef<typeof MyComponentViewNative>();

  public state: MyComponentState = {
    permissionsGranted: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    ...
    this.setState({ permissionsGranted: true });
  }

  start(filePath: String) {
    callViewMethod(this.viewRef, 'start', filePath);
  }

  render() {
    const { permissionsGranted } = this.state;

    return permissionsGranted ? (
      <MyComponentViewNative {...this.props} ref={this.viewRef} />
    ) : (
      <View {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

function callViewMethod(
  viewRef: React.RefObject<typeof MyComponentViewNative>,
  methodName: string,
  ...params: any[]
) {
  if (viewRef.current == null) {
    return;
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    NativeModules.MyComponentViewNative[methodName].apply(
      NativeModules.MyComponentViewNative,
      [findNodeHandle(viewRef.current), ...params]
    );
  } else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
      findNodeHandle(viewRef.current),
      methodName,
      params
    );
  }
}
```

My goal is to create a native component wrapper class `MyComponentView`, get a ref `viewRef` to an instance of the native component `MyComponentViewNative` in it and call it's method `start`. Seems I'm using ref the right way (at list it worked for me in plain JS many times), but setting its type is a thing I can't figure out.

So, tsc gives me a bunch of errors a-la the following one:

```
src/index.tsx:124:23 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'HostComponent<MyComponentProps> | (() => never)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | ComponentClass<any, any> | Component<any, any, any> | null'.
  Type '() => never' is not assignable to type 'number | ComponentClass<any, any> | Component<any, any, any> | null'.

124       [findNodeHandle(viewRef.current), ...params]
```

What am I doing wrong? What type should I use for the viewRef property? Or. maybe, I can somehow skip setting types explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some time I returned back to this problem and figured things out:

1. I switched to custom ref callback instead of calling `createRef` as I need some init actions to be done right after my native component is instantiated

   ```
   private onRef = (ref: ComponentClass<any>) => {
     this.viewRef = ref;

     //...init code goes here
   };
   ```
2. I used a generic `ComponentClass<any>` as a type of `viewRef` instead of typed `RefObject`:

   ```
   private viewRef: ComponentClass<any> | null = null;
   ```
3. I moved `ref` property out of `MyComponentProps` to a separate type:

   ```
   type SpecialProps = {
     ref?: (ref: ComponentClass<any>) => void | ComponentClass<any> | null;
   };
   ```

   So now I retrieve my native component in the following way:

   ```
   const MyComponentViewNative =
     UIManager.getViewManagerConfig(ComponentName) != null
     ? requireNativeComponent<MyComponentProps & SpecialProps>(ComponentName)
     : () => {
         throw new Error(LINKING_ERROR);
       };
   ```

And now it all looks like:

```
type MyComponentProps = {
  style?: ViewStyle;
};

type SpecialProps = {
  ref?: (ref: ComponentClass<any>) => void | ComponentClass<any> | null;
};

type MyComponentState = {
  permissionsGranted?: Boolean;
};

const ComponentName = 'MyComponentView';

const MyComponentViewNative =
  UIManager.getViewManagerConfig(ComponentName) != null
  ? requireNativeComponent<MyComponentProps & SpecialProps>(ComponentName)
  : () => {
      throw new Error(LINKING_ERROR);
  };

export class MyComponentView extends React.PureComponent<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
  private viewRef: viewRef: ComponentClass<any> | null = null;

  public state: MyComponentState = {
    permissionsGranted: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    //...some init code here

    this.setState({ permissionsGranted: true });
  }

  public start(filePath: String) {
    callViewMethod(this.viewRef, 'start', filePath);
  }

  private onRef = (ref: ComponentClass<any>) => {
    this.viewRef = ref;

    //...init code goes here
  };

  render() {
    const { permissionsGranted } = this.state;

    return permissionsGranted ? (
      <MyComponentViewNative {...this.props} ref={this.onRef} />
    ) : (
      <View {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

function callViewMethod(
  viewRef: ComponentClass<any> | null,
  methodName: string,
  ...params: any[]
) {
  if (viewRef == null) {
    return;
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    NativeModules.MyComponentViewNative[methodName].apply(
      NativeModules.MyComponentViewNative,
      [findNodeHandle(viewRef.current), ...params]
    );
  } else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
      findNodeHandle(viewRef.current),
      methodName,
      params
    );
  }
}
```